# SharePoint Print Dispform.aspx

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list-form, display-form, printing

I am doing some testing on SharePoint lists/forms and am stuck a bit on a print function/button that I want to implement in one of my forms.

Out of a list that I created with LOTS of columns, I formed a new display form (`DispForm.aspx`) and use this as a means for users to view their form after registration.

After searching over the internet I came across lots of articles and blog posts concerning this but could not use the existing workarounds in my case.

I need to print the display form but when using the 
`<a "href="javascript:window.print()">Print</a>"` script, it does print the form, but with the buttons also, which should not be the case.

Is there a way, if that's not too much asking, to print only the columns/fields/rows in the form?

Comment: The way i have done this in the past was to create a new custom form and place everything into a DIV (or other container) and give it an ID. You can then follow this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7532581/5051773 on how to print everything in that div.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Roland, much appreciated.
I have a question though, I add the new form in a new container, which can be done in SP designer i'm sure. the in the javascript, I specify the Div name in the function right?
I hoe this is goint to work.

Comment: I added a <Div> to contain only the columns/content to be printed as advised.  I then created a button with an onclick event to call the function as you specified.  
Works perfectly fine and I guess this answers my question. 

Thanks a lot for the help.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

**Button**

```
 <input type="button" onclick="printDiv('DivName')" style="width: 64px; height: 64px; background-image: url(print.jpg);"/>
```

**Javascript**

```
    function printDiv(DivName) {

        //Get the HTML of div
        var divElements = document.getElementById(DivName).innerHTML;

        //Get the HTML of whole page
        var oldPage = document.body.innerHTML;

        //Reset the page's HTML with div's HTML only
        document.body.innerHTML = divElements;

        //Print Page
        window.print();

        //Restore orignal HTML
        document.body.innerHTML = oldPage;

    }
</script>​​
```

Comment: This won't work because for SharePoint inline script tags like onclick aren't allowed. have to bind the event from javascript outside of the html.

Comment: I used the script above and it works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: Oh okay. Every time I do this using JSOM and put the kind of button you described in a content editor, it strips the inline tags. How did you place the button on the page? Is it in the aspx form or did you use a content editor web part?

Comment: What I did is simple: 
- Open the list
- Form web parts - New Display Form
- In the display form, click on site actions and edit the page
- On the top of the page, you will find a container which says "Click here      to add a new web part", click on that and add the content editor.
- Click in the content editor and in the top ribbon, click on edit HTML source
- Here I add the code for the button first, and then the javascript a few lines below.

Answer (score 0):

- All Data Content Include `Div Tag`.
- Written code `OnClientClick` event..

  `OnClientClick="window.print(); return false"`